# Error when executing the command "Build()" in my application startup with IWebHostBuilder

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependency-injection

I am trying to upload my API to AWS Lambda (Gateway), but I get an error when doing the Build() of my application to obtain the services injected by "dependency injection", can anyone help me please?

My code where it throws the error to initialize the system is the following:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer;
using API_StoreSysBackendAdministrative.Extensions;
namespace API_StoreSysBackendAdministrative;

public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
  public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

  protected override async void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
  {
    try
    {
         var app =
            builder
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseLambdaServer()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

        ServiceProvider = app.Services;
        ServiceLocator.Provider = ServiceProvider;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{ex.Message} \n Exception: {ex.ToString()}");
    }

  }
}
```

The error it throws me is the following:

```
Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Building this implementation of IWebHostBuilder is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs I've seen it seems that `Init` method should only make setup actions (like `.UseStartup<Startup>()`) and the actual app will be build by the AWS framework:

```cs
public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
  protected override async void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
  {
        var app =
            builder
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseLambdaServer()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
  }
}
```

Even if it would be possible to build it manually (and it would be possible to build the same app twice, which is not in some cases) it could lead to different problems in the app like multiple instances of `Singleton` services, or missing service registration done by AWS infrastructure.

I highly recommend to refactor your app so you don't need service locator which [can be considered as anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) (I'm quite sure that there are better ways to achieve your goals then double building app).